# Converting content of files to uppercase

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I have a shell script called "concat" that currently takes command line arguments and prints the contents of files named on the command line. I need to now create a script called "concatconvert" that calls the "concat" script, takes the contents of files and converts them.

The following is the code of my script "concat":

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
printf "Usage: concat FILE ... \nDescription: Concatenates FILE(s) 
to standard output separating them with divider -----.\n" >&2
exit 1
fi

for var in "$@"
do
    if [[ ! -e "$var" ]]; then
            printf "One or more files does not exist\n" >$2
            exit 1
    fi
done

for var in "$@"
do
    if [ -f "$var" ]; then
            cat $var
            printf -- "-----\n"
    fi
done
exit 0
```

I am going to be calling "concat" using

```
#!/bin/bash
./concat
```

in the concatconvert script.

Concatconvert is going to take arguments "-u" and "-l"

Ultimately the script would be executed as:

```
./concatconvert -u test1.txt test2.txt
```

> -u converts contents of files to uppercase.

For example, `"This is a test"` becomes `"THIS IS A TEST"`.

> -l converts contents of files to lowercase.

For example, `"This is a test"` becomes `"this is a test"`.

Only one option can be provided at a time.
I am not too sure where to begin on this. I appreciate any help.

Comment: just pipe through `tr` or the like

Comment: Well here is what i have so far.                                                                '#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        printf "Usage: concatconvert [-u|-l| FILE ... \nDescription: concatenates FILE(s) to standard output separating them with divider -----. Optional first argument -u or -l converts contents to uppercase or lowercase, respectively."
        exit 1
fi

./concat

if [ $1 == '-u' ]; then
        tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
        exit 0
fi'

Comment: well you should be passing filenames to `./concat` no? Then pipe the output to `tr` as @Pacifist shows below

Comment: There is no question in your question. You do not ask a question or state what specific thing you need help with. Do you need help parsing/interpreting the command line and its arguments and switches? Do you need help reading the files and processing their contents? Do you want to process the contents with bash operations or is it okay to call external commands to do that?

Comment: The ./concat has to be called by ./concatconvert in the script. So it needs to provide the same functionality as ./concat but then also adding in the functionality of -u or -l commands

Comment: look up argument parsing -- you need to `shift` off the flags and do `./concat "$@"`

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit confusing to explain. This is how the concat script is called.              ./concat test1.txt test2.txt   -The ./concatconvert should look similar like this: ./concatconvert -u test1.txt test2.txt and it needs to call the concat script. So i am having trouble having both of these scripts work in conjuction.

Comment: right, in your concatconvert: `[[ "$1" == "-u" ]] && shift && ./concat "$@"`

Comment: I see, so i can just do if [[ "$1" == "-u" ]] && shift && ./concat "$@" then use the tr command on it?

Comment: Why "one or more files does not exist"?  As a user, I would find that error message particular annoying.  You should name the file. eg "$var does not exist".

Comment: I just adjusted it to $var does not exist. Thank you for the pointer. I had it that more for just testing so I knew it was working properly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `tr` command as mentioned by @jenesaisquoi.

> The tr command in UNIX is a command-line utility for translating or
>   deleting characters.

To use it to change everything to lower case command would be :

```
echo "This is Test" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
this is test
```

To use it to change everything to upper case command would be :

```
echo "This is Test" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
THIS IS TEST
```

To use it for a file use below command :

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < filename
```